# Data not showing up in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a PHP Calendar that I made, and it alows you to add a event..except the problem is that when I add an event now, it shows up on phpmyadmin as a new record but it does not have any info in it. Please Help :P

```
          <html>

 <head> 

     <title> 
     Calendar - event added 
     </title> 
     <body> 
     <?php 
     $link = mysql_connect('tealdevcom.ipagemysql.com', '*******', '********');  
     if (!$link) {  
         die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  
     }  

     mysql_select_db(cal1);  


     $sql="INSERT INTO cal1_table (event, cal_date) 
     VALUES 
     ('$_POST[title]','$_POST[date]')"; 

     if (!mysql_query($sql,$link)) 
       {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      } 
     echo "event added"; 

     mysql_close($link) 
     ?> 
     <br> 
     Go back to the <a href="http://www.development.tealdev.com">Calendar</a> 
     </body> 
     </html>
```

Comment: Please, please, research and start using prepared SQL statements, or at least escape the form input data on the server side. Your example above is hugely prone to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Have you echo'd the $sql variable to see what it's contents are?

Comment: @CoryLarson - Are you sure? Doesn't look like it will run to me. But then again, it's pretty hard to read. (Oh, and you're right btw. `:P`)

Comment: @chrisf1288: I could come up with an event title value that could destroy your database, among many other things. It's very bad practice to directly insert values submitted from a form into your database. Just think what would happen if I submitted the value `oops',null); DROP TABLE cal1_table; --` as the title...

Comment: he just means you're not sanitizing/stripping the form input.  So someone could insert something in the form that alters a SQL statement, and then does bad things.  It's not that big of a deal, worry about that later.  See the debugging examples below, debugging is fun!  (but know that some jerk will hack your live dev site for fun if you don't sanitize input)

Answer (score 0):

Add some "printf" (PHP echo" statements to your code to verify $_POST[title] and $_POST[date] aren't blank.

It wouldn't hurt to echo your $sql statement, too.

Basically, you need to debug

1) Your input

2) Your SQL query

Answer (score 0):

In general : If a query succeeds, but the data is showing up as blank in your gui you can always test this way :

1) Run a query (select colA, colB from table1) on the console - check that the data is there.
2) If data is there, modify your query to (select length(colA), length(colB)) .  Now you will know if the data has blank characters or binary characters in it, because length will not be empty.

After wards you should

3) Put the db insert into a new method.

4) Add a UNIT test to your code to run the method and ensure that it throws an exception if null or empty data is added to the query insert parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using some way of passing query parameters separately rather than embedding them directly in your query string. As mentioned elsewhere this leaves you wide open to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). One example would be to use [PDO objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

e.g.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=tealdevcom.ipagemysql.com;dbname=$cal1', $user, $pass);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO cal1_table (event, cal_date) VALUES (:title, :date)");
$stmt->bindParam("title", $_POST['title']);
$stmt->bindParam("date", $_POST['date']);
$stmt->execute();
```

I find the phpinfo(); function useful for debugging whether $_GET/$_POST contain what I think they do. Perhaps your data isn't being posted correctly.